# NSRangeException when trying to set default UIPickerView value

Tags: objective-c, ipad, exception, uipickerview, popover

I've got a UIPickerView in a popover. I'm just trying to set the default/starting value of the picker view before the popover gets shown. Here's the code I'm using to create and show the popover (in the method handling a touch up button action):

```
- (IBAction) handleClickStepTimeButton: (id)sender
{
    UIViewController *timePickerController = [UIViewController alloc];

    UIPickerView *timePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 180)];
    timePicker.delegate = self;
    timePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [timePickerController.view addSubview:timePicker];

    UIPopoverController *timePickerPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:timePickerController];
    timePickerPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 200);

    UIButton *stepTimeButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    [timePickerPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(stepTimeButton.frame.size.width, (stepTimeButton.frame.size.height / 2), 1, 1) inView:stepTimeButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    [timePicker selectRow:(currentStep.length - 1) inComponent:1 animated:YES];
}
```

I have no concerns creating the popover and UIPickerView each time this button is clicked because it won't happen very often and because the values of the UIPickerView are simply a small number of integers. Here's the code I'm using to add the values to the view:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 8;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)rowId forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (rowId + 1)];
}
```

My problem is that every time I go to show the popover, I get an NSRangeException on the `[timePicker selectRow...` line. This kind of makes sense to me because the UIPickerView isn't showing yet. But using that logic...how is it ever possible to set a default/starting value for a UIPickerView?

I'm sure there's a simple solution here but I'm just not seeing it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the number of components are valid and `currentStep.length - 1` isn't greater than `8`.

You main problem is that you aren't setting the `dataSource` of the picker. Add

```
timePicker.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: I have set it to 1 component. `currentStep.length - 1` equates to 2. I set the class to implement `UIPickerViewDataSource` and set `timePicker.dataSource = self;`, but still I get the same exception. Are you sure it's not an non-initialised thing? Seems to make sense, plus the details of the error message says `index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`, which would lead to that conclusion. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just found the issue. Components are 0-indexed. I changed it to `[timePicker selectRow:(currentStep.length - 1) inComponent:0 animated:YES];` and it works happily.